# Scala, for comprehensions and EitherT

Tags: scala, scala-cats

My technology stack is

- Play Framework 2.6
- Scala 2.12.6
- Play-Slick 3.0.0
- Cats 1.4.0

I am trying to achieve this function to update a row in the database

```
def update(userId: Long, user: User) = {
  (for {
    _ <- EitherT(updateUser(userId, user))
    user: User <- EitherT(findById(userId))
    userProfile: userProfile <- EitherT(userProfileRepository.findById(user.userProfileId))
  } yield (user, userProfile).map {
    case (user: User, userProfile: UserProfile) =>
      val response = new UserResponse(user, userProfile)
      Right(response)
    case error =>
      val str = s"update failure: $error"
      Left(str)
  }
}
```

but when I try to compile this code with EitherT I am getting

> value withFilter is not a member of cats.data.EitherT

Comment: It seems [`EitherT`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/data/EitherT.html) has no `filter`/`withFilter` methods. `withFilter` is required with Scala 2.12 in order to pattern match in for comprehensions. (`filter` could be implemented with `flatMap`, not sure about the `withFilter` method, that might not be lazy enough.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to pattern-match inside the for-comprehension (although it looks only as innocent type declaration). But for pattern-matching inside a for-comprehension `withFilter` implementation is required (think of what should happen if pattern-matching fails?). So remove matching over types and it should work:

```
def update(userId: Long, user: User) = {
  (for {
    _ <- EitherT(updateUser(userId, user))
    user <- EitherT(findById(userId))
    userProfile <- EitherT(userProfileRepository.findById(user.userProfileId))
  } yield (user, userProfile).map {
    case (user: User, userProfile: UserProfile) =>
      val response = new UserResponse(user, userProfile)
      Right(response)
    case error =>
      val str = s"update failure: $error"
      Left(str)
  }
}
```

Comment: you're welcome! I'm glad you asked, it's a common problem with for comprehension

Comment: @MikhailGolubtsov, what the difference between your code and the code in the question? Cannot see it.

Comment: @Alexandr have a closer look left to `<-`, a semicolon and type definitions should be omitted.

Comment: @MikhailGolubtsov, found! Thank you!